# Looking for a variation of waterfall plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have a 3-dimensional data to be plotted in matlab. The data set are built by stacking 10 exponential curves with different parameters along y directions such as

```
  x = 0:0.01:15;
  x0 = 0.5;
  y = [beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4, beta5, beta6, beta7, beta8, beta9, beta10];
  Z(1, :) = A*exp(-(x-x0).^2/beta1);
  Z(2, :) = A*exp(-(x-x0).^2/beta2);
  Z(3, :) = A*exp(-(x-x0).^2/beta3);
  Z(4, :) = A*exp(-(x-x0).^2/beta4);
  ...
  Z(10, :) = A*exp(-(x-x0).^2/beta10);
  % here A could be change based on beta too (no code shown here)
```

I am trying to plot Z with waterfall except for I don't want the height (i.e. the vertical line) appears on the edge. I don't know if there is any other way to plot the data as waterfall-like curves but without those vertical lines. Thanks

[image: how to get rid the vertical lines as circled in the following figures]

Comment: the problem of using plot3 is 1) it is plotted with lines instead of patch with surface 2) plot3(x, y, z) requires the same dimension among x and y but in my case, they are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it is plotted with lines instead of patch with surface".
In other words, you want the boundary lines to be invisible. Well that's no trivial feat as the boundary lines are separate from any color scheme you can directly include. What you need to do is get the data after it drawn then modify it accordingly:

e.g.

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
h = waterfall (X,Y,Z);
CD = get (h, 'CData');
CD(1,:) = nan;
CD(end-2:end,:) = nan;
set (h, 'CData', CD)
```

note that `CD(1,:)` is for the "rising" boundary, while `CD(end-2:end-1,:)` is for the falling boundary, and `CD(end,:)` is for the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Rasman. It works great. Just kinda curious, is that any way to make the region under zero transparent? Thanks anyway.

Comment: you can vary FaceAlpha to value less the 1 (`set (h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.3)`), but it will cost you the whole boundary color scheme. I'm sure there is another way to compensate for this, I just haven't figured it out

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old post, but the below will make the region under the curve transparent:

```
figure;
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(10);
handle_figure = waterfall( X, Y, Z );
set( handle_figure, 'FaceColor', 'none' );
```